# I want to upload file/document using protractor

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, protractor

In our Angular application, there is a restriction that we cannot add file more than 4MB. But the code I am executing always results in this pop up saying"Your file is greater than 4MB" although the file I am uploading is in kbs. 
**What I want to perform:**

1. I have a upload form
2. The first field is attach document, on which I have to click on
   upload icon.
3. File window pop up will be shown. From which I have to select one
   file
4. Click open, the selected file name is shown on this attach document
   field.

My code is :

```
var path = require('path');
var fileToUpload = 'C:\Users\r\project photos\11182717-Business-woman--Stock-Photo-lawyer.jpg',
absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);  element(by.xpath('html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div[2]/a/i')).click();     
element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replaced the back slashes with forward slashes:
C:/Users/r/project photos/11182717-Business-woman--Stock-Photo-lawyer.jpg